how to get three.js crossFadeTo() working
So I've downloaded a mixamo character and, separately, an animation pack. I've set up a scene with lights, cameras, textured ground and all. I load all the animations and then, I play one of the animations. I setup an eventListener to tell me when the animation ends (All this is working!) THEN I attempt to crossFadeTo a random endAction. HERE the character fades to its tpose (this is not what I want). Here is the relevant code:
    loadAnimations(){
        const loader = new FBXLoader();
        var that = this;
        for(var i=0;i<this.animationFiles.length;i++){
            loader.load(that.animationFiles[i],
                function(animObj){
                    that.animations.push(animObj.animations[0]);
                },
                function(){
                    console.log(Math.round(100*((that.animations.length+1)/that.animationFiles.length))+'% loaded');
                    if((that.animations.length+1)==that.animationFiles.length) {
                        that.finishedLoading.bind(that)
                        that.finishedLoading();
                    }
                }
            );
        }

    }
    finishedLoading(a){
        console.log(this.animations)
        this.tpose.animations = this.animations;
        this.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(this.tpose);
        this.action = this.mixer.clipAction(this.tpose.animations[1]);
        this.action.play();
        this.mixer.addEventListener('loop',this.animationEnd.bind(this));
    }
    animationEnd(){
        console.log('animation end');
        var i= Math.floor(Math.random()*this.tpose.animations.length);
        console.log('playing animation#'+i);
        const endAction = this.mixer.clipAction(this.tpose.animations[i]);
        endAction.enabled = true;
        endAction.setEffectiveTimeScale(1);
        endAction.setEffectiveWeight(1);
        endAction.time = 0;
        endAction.weight=1;

        this.action.crossFadeTo ( endAction, 1, true);
    }

I got all the endAction stuff in animationEnd() from various examples online. In particular, I gather from this that its especially important to set the weight to 1.

I'm using three@0.132.2 BTW

Seems no one knows
